# .closest not working in Jquery

Tags: jquery

Please can you guys have a look. As far as I can tell the closest function isn't working, because the class isn't added:

```
 <div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label">Address:</label>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cardAppDto.pdcCardAppEntityDto.homeCardAppAddressDto.addrTwo" value="${cardApplicationDto.cardAppDto.pdcCardAppEntityDto.homeCardAppAddressDto.addrTwo}">
    <p class="help-block flush--bottom ">
        <a href="">Can't find your address?</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

I need to add class "has-errors" to the "form-group" div and then do some other things with the label and message. Here is my JQuery. It looks like it isn't selecting the div, or not adding the class.

```
groupDiv = $("#cardAppDto.pdcCardAppEntityDto.homeCardAppAddressDto.addrTwo").closest('div.form-group');
groupDiv.addClass('has-error');
groupDiv.find('label.control-label').prepend('<i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-f2 color--error"></i>&nbsp;');
groupDiv.append('<span class="help-block">${error.defaultMessage}</span>');
```

Or is there another error?

Comment: `$("[name='cardAppDto.pdcCardAppEntityDto.homeCardAppAddressDto.addrTwo']").closest('div.form-group');`

Comment: Instead of using the name attribute use the id attribute for input

Comment: You don't have any element with that ID, so nothing is selected.

Comment: Hi Pranav. I really liked your comment as well. Please put it in an answer so I can mark it up at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the ID selector but your element doesn't have an id attribute. Please check below code

```
<input 
  type="text"
  class="form-control" 
  id="cardAppDto.pdcCardAppEntityDto.homeCardAppAddressDto.addrTwo"
  name="cardAppDto.pdcCardAppEntityDto.homeCardAppAddressDto.addrTwo" 
  value="${cardApplicationDto.cardAppDto.pdcCardAppEntityDto.homeCardAppAddressDto.addrTwo}"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label">Address:</label>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cardAppDto.pdcCardAppEntityDto.homeCardAppAddressDto.addrTwo" id="cardAppDto.pdcCardAppEntityDto.homeCardAppAddressDto.addrTwo" value="${cardApplicationDto.cardAppDto.pdcCardAppEntityDto.homeCardAppAddressDto.addrTwo}">
    <p class="help-block flush--bottom ">
        <a href="">Can't find your address?</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

And your Js :

```
groupDiv = $("#cardAppDto.pdcCardAppEntityDto.homeCardAppAddressDto.addrTwo").closest('div.form-group');
groupDiv.addClass('has-error');
groupDiv.find('label.control-label').prepend('<i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-f2 color--error"></i>&nbsp;');
groupDiv.append('<span class="help-block">${error.defaultMessage}</span>');
```

Comment: I can't tell what the difference is. Please add an explanation. Don't make me play the "spot the difference" game.

Comment: He was using ID in jquery for accessing input so added ID in input just as the name.